# Remove box in beamer slides

Tags: beamer

Given the following minimal example of my presentation

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}

\title{Nice talk}


\frame{\titlepage} 


\frame{\frametitle{Agenda}\tableofcontents} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction} 
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}


\subsection{beginning} 
\frame{ \frametitle{state of the art}

some explanation

}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Results} 
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}


\subsection{outcome} 
\frame{ \frametitle{results obtained}

some results 

}


\end{document}
```

I wonder what is the name of the box that appears above all slides (Table of contents?) and how can I remove it completely on this case (without changing the style -colors, etc-)

Comment: Delete the line `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}`. It will change the style but remove the top box.

Comment: No, because I really like that style

Comment: Another ugly hack would be to add the `plain` option to every frame, i.e. to replace every occurrence of `\frame{` with `\frame[plain]{`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often called the navigation bar or headline bar.

You can remove it by tweaking the specified theme (e.g. try adding

`\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`

after selecting the theme - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183258/how-to-get-rid-of-navigation-bars-in-beamer for more discussion on this) or you could consider a different theme that does not have this by default (see sites that show sample themes (e.g. http://www.pletscher.org/writings/latex/beamerthemes.php or themes of presentations you like and also [the beamer user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf))